# the up() function is not working in turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

i am trying to create a class that inherits from turtle but for some reason every time i create an object of that class it will still draw with the pen

```
from turtle import Turtle

class Player(Turtle):

    def __init__(self,num):

        super().__init__()

        self.up()
        self.color("white")

        self.shape("square")

        self.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1, outline=None)

        if num == 1:

            self.goto(-350,0)
        else:

            self.goto (350,0)

    def up(self):
        new_y = self.ycor() + 20
        self.goto(x=self.xcor(), y=new_y)

    def down(self):
        new_y = self.ycor() - 20
        self.goto(x=self.xcor(), y=new_y)
```

this is the script

i also tried calling the function in the main page but still nothing

Comment: Your class does not have access to the standard Turtle `up()` method, because you overrode it with your own method named `up()` that does something entirely different.

Comment: it worked thank you i didn't notice

Answer (score 0):

Your class doesn't have the same `method up()` as the normal turtle class. Your method replaced the normal method, so your `main.py` thinks you are calling the `player.up()` instead of the `turtle.up()`